# How do I get my search bar and surrounding text to be 25% of the whitespace below the navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, algolia

I would like my search bar and "Camera search" to be about 75% up from the bottom of the screen, so 25% of the white space when measured from the navbar. I'm having issues vertically aligning it.

I've tried using `vertical-align: 25%` in my CSS file for the `#search-header` id, but to no avail.

```
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Camera search."">
  <meta name="author" content="author">

  <title>Camera App</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="{% static 'core/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'core/css/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Angolia search CDN and CSS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img alt="brand" src="{% static 'core/img/logo_with_tagline.png' %}" ></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Search section -->
  <div id="search-header" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-9 text-center mx-auto">
        <h3>Camera search</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xl-5 ais-InstantSearch mx-auto">
            <input id="searchbow" name="q" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="false" spellcheck="false" class="form-control" type="search" />        
        </div>
        <div id="hits"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="hits">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-9 text-center">
          <h1>text</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>



  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="{% static 'core/vendor/jquery/jquery.slim.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'core/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>

  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/algoliasearch,algoliasearch.helper"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'core/js/search.js' %}"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

```
/* custom.css */

.navbar-brand > img {
    max-height: 40px;
  }  

#search-header {
  vertical-align: 25%;
}
```

Here's the results as of right now: https://jsfiddle.net/3tf780np/
Here is an image of something similar i'm trying to achieve, except without the big text saying "A list of remote jobs".

[image: Picture of what i'm trying to achieve.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use margin-top instead of vertical-align on search-header to adjust spacing from the navbar

Comment: I don't realy understand what your problem is, but try to use top:45px for example.